# How to save config file of odoo?

Tags: python, odoo

I am run my odoo server using this command `python odoo.py -s -c conf`, according to the [odoo command line document](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/reference/cmdline.html#reference-cmdline-config) **-s** means saves the server configuration to the current configuration file **-c** means provide an alternate configuration file to a path.

On windows this command is okay to save a conf file with many parameter. But on my ubuntu machine, it only saves an empty file named "conf".

So how can I save my conf file successfully so that I could modify it in the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use only `python odoo.py -s`, the saved file should be `$HOME/.openerp_serverrc`
In you case you give a  alternative configuration file, so `odoo` should have permission to write to that file:

```
sudo chown odoo: conf
```

Comment: Yes I got it, odoo have no permission to write the conf file, chown works. But in your first solution, I cannot find .openerp_serverrc anywhere in my system... I'm new to ubuntu... what does that $HOME meas? a specific path? But i did an all-disk search and find no file named .openerp_serverc

Comment: @SummerSun `HOME` is an environment variable that contains path to home directory same as `~`.So the config file path is `~/.openerp_serverrc`.

Comment: but where exactly is the openerp_serverrc stored? I don't know what my environment var is... is there a relative link according to my odoo.py path?

Comment: @SummerSun It is stored in your home directory, Run `ls ~/.openerp_serverrc` in terminal to see the path.

Comment: WoLy, it says "cannot access /home/summersun/.openerp_serverrc: No such file or directory".... i think there's no such file in my system...

Comment: @SummerSun You should run `python odoo.py -s` to tell odoo to create it for you.